# Update count after returning result

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking for a way to update the count for the database after finding the result of a product but it keeps returning an error and/or not updating the count. I found ways to update the counts out right but not after finding a result. If i'm blind please redirect me. My apologies if I overlooked anything. RAM

```
<?php

//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.


require_once '../connect/connect.php';

$usertable = "UPC_Product";
$yourfield2 = "Product";
$yourfield1 = "UPCA";
$yourfield3 = "Gluten Free";
$yourfield4 = "Company";
$yourfield5 = "search_cnt";
$yourfield6 = "CompName";
$yourfield7 = "id";
$search_id = $_POST["search_id"];

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to
            connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE UPCA = $search_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield2"];

        $upca = $row["$yourfield1"];

        $gluten = $row["$yourfield3"];

        $count = $row["$yourfield5"];

        $id = $row["$yourfield7"];
    }

//update count 
    $ucount = "UPDATE $usertable SET search_cnt = ($count + 1)";
    mysql_query($ucount);
}
?>


<head>
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="../images/GluteFreefavicon.jpg">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Result Page</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="English" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" media="screen" />
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-39600334-1', 'glutefree.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="header">
<a href="index.html"><img src="/images/glutefreefacebookbanner.jpg"/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <center> <a href="index.html">Home</a> &middot; <a href="../search">Search</a> &middot; <a href="../application">Application</a> &middot; <a href="../newuser">Register</a> &middot; <a href="../contact_us">Contact Us</a> &middot; <a href="../aboutus">About Us</a> &middot; <a href="">Games</a>

            </center>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <center>Your Results
                <br/>
            </center>Product:
            <?php echo $name; ?>
            <br/>
            <div class="product">Gluten Free?
                <?php echo $gluten; ?>
                <br>
                <br>UPC:
                <?php echo $upca;?>
                <br>Search count:
                <?php echo $count;?>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>No Result? Click <a href="../submit_error.html">here</a> to fill out information on the product you were searching for.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div> 
</div> 
<div id="footer">
    </a>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: how is it related to css???

Comment: You are calling the count variable before the function is actually processed.

Comment: Sorry about the css and I was originally getting a unexpected t_variable but then I

Comment: get no error and no count update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**correction 1** :- I think you need to write your update query below the while loop. because you are using `$count` variable before creating it.

Also please specify if you need to increase `count` for individual row or total.

If you need to update count for individual row then you have write query inside while loop.

```
UPDATE $usertable SET search_cnt = ($count + 1) WHERE id_column_name = $id;
```

**correction 2**:- You are calling `mysql_query($ucount);` in wrong place. this should be below `update` query.

**Correction 3** :- as `$count` is your count number then obviously it will not be your column name , write down you column name in update query.

```
UPDATE $usertable SET count_column_name = ($count + 1)
```

**Corrected Block of code:-**

```
<?php

//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.


require_once '../connect/connect.php';

$usertable = "UPC_Product";
$yourfield2 = "Product";
$yourfield1 = "UPCA";
$yourfield3 = "Gluten Free";
$yourfield4 = "Company";
$yourfield5 = "search_cnt";
$yourfield6 = "CompName";
$yourfield7 = "id";
$search_id = $_POST["search_id"];

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to
            connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE UPCA = $search_id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield2"];

        $upca = $row["$yourfield1"];

        $gluten = $row["$yourfield3"];

        $count = $row["$yourfield5"];

        $id = $row["$yourfield7"];
    }

//update count
    // Please write here count column name not $count. I have write count at this time. 
    $ucount = "UPDATE $usertable SET search_cnt = ($count + 1)";
    mysql_query($ucount);
}
?>
```

Comment: You guys are fantastic at answering these questions but it's still not working. could it possibly be something server side preventing it from not working?

Comment: what is your count column name?

Comment: search_cnt on the mysql database

Comment: So your update query will be `$ucount = "UPDATE $usertable SET search_cnt = ($count + 1)";`

Comment: So to prevent it from updating all search counts and only for the one set for search_id what do I do? I apologize I am really new at this whole thing.

Comment: This will prove to be helpful as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html --> Also, you can manually update your database and use the syntax from there too.

Comment: Agreed @BuddhistBeast ! . And I think your column data type might be integer and you are trying to store string. so try with `$count = 1;`

Comment: Yes my type is integer I'm really sorry I should know how to write this up better RAM

Comment: for those wondering the site I'm working on is www.glutefree.com/search

Comment: @GluteFree No problem :) Enjoy Learning.

Comment: but I have a question regarding the fact that it updates everything in the db. How does having it set as in affect it in a negative way

Comment: Sorry @GluteFree I didn't get you properly. You can simply tell me how many fields you need to update and on what basis. if you read my correction1 point I have mentioned If you need update individually then how can you achieve.

Comment: I just need to update that specific row that is searched for from the page before which specifically calls to search_id if that makes any sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43727/discussion-between-roopendra-and-glutefree)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is rearrange a function to get the correct count. Below should be the right code.

```
<?php
//Variables for connecting to your database.
//These variable values come from your hosting account.


require_once '../connect/connect.php';

$usertable = "UPC_Product";
$yourfield2 = "Product";
$yourfield1 = "UPCA";
$yourfield3 = "Gluten Free";
$yourfield4 = "Company";
$yourfield5 = "search_cnt";
$yourfield6 = "CompName";
$yourfield7 = "id";
$search_id = $_POST["search_id"];

//Connecting to your database
mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ("Unable to
            connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

//Fetching from your database table.
$query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE UPCA = $search_id" ;
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row["$yourfield2"];

        $upca = $row["$yourfield1"];

        $gluten = $row["$yourfield3"];

        $count = $row["$yourfield5"];

        $id = $row["$yourfield7"];

}
}
$ucount = "UPDATE $usertable SET $count = ($count + 1)";
mysql_query($ucount) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

To be more specific - You were trying to call:

```
$ucount = "UPDATE $usertable SET $count = ($count + 1)";
```

before you actually updated the $count method in the while loop.

Comment: using this it will no longer throw an error but it still does not update the count in the database :(

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to call the query again. The above code should work now, and it should update your database :)

Comment: is the " ' " required?

Comment: I fixed that haha, that snuck in there.

Comment: Can you add the 'or die' portion to your text and let me know what it produces? Also, you need to put the column name that you are trying to update, not just $count.